# android:ListActivity unable to open sdcard mp3 neither play mp3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, android-studio

`ListActivity` closes when trying to open saved recordings from the SD card in recording activity and new activity, showing that ListView starts but not open sdcard contents mp3 from externalsdcard to play file in it!  *Thanks*

Here is my code

```
public class Droid extends ListActivity {

    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songlist);
        updateSongList();
    }

    public void updateSongList() {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.song_item, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);
        }
    }

    class Filter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".3gp"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        currentPosition = position;
        playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
    }

    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            // Setup listener so next song starts automatically
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    nextSong();
                }

            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void nextSong() {
        if (++currentPosition >= songs.size()) {
            // Last song, just reset currentPosition
            currentPosition = 0;
        } else {
            // Play next song
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

**songlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="@string/media"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**song_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Force closes new class Droid on option menu**

```
    case R.id.droid:
      Intent dr = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Droid.class);
      startActivity(dr);
      return true;
```

Comment: Need to see the stack trace

Comment: check ans and give response

Comment: Didn't fetch external sdcard mp3's for playing

Comment: may be your songs list is null or empty

Comment: still have it in sdcard but unable to fetch file and play

Comment: add this to manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: thk but already place this in mnifest

Answer (score 0):

You did not declared your Drod Activity at your Manifest.

If all other works, else you should post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

**change this**

```
 public class Droid extends ListActivity
```

**to**

```
  public class Droid extends Activity

  // U already define listview in xml so no need to extends activity as ListActivity


// implements this method,
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            currentPosition = position;
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
        }
    });
```

Comment: `onListItemClick` err want to play it also